# How to find people working for a company from LinkedIn?

Tags: linkedin

Looking at a personal profile, it is possible to find the company each one is working for, but how is it possible to do the searching starting from a company?

I can find the company starting from a LinkedIn personal page of any employee, but when I click on the company link I can only view the company page with no more links.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Advanced Search](https://www.linkedin.com/vsearch/f?adv=true) functionality to search based on company or many other factors:

[image]